# Postgres Combining two write queries inside a transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a transaction that updates two rows on two different tables

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE comments SET upvoted = upvoted + 1 
WHERE comment_id = $1 AND posted_by = $2;

INSERT INTO commentsvoted(id, user_id, votes, thread_id) 
VALUES($1, $2, true, $3);

COMMIT;
```

This query works in pgadmin but does not work in lambda and returns the error

```
cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement
```

How would I combine these two writes into one statement? And how come it does not work outside of pgadmin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres, you can write this as a single statement:

```
WITH u as (
      UPDATE comments
          SET upvoted = upvoted + 1 
          WHERE comment_id = $1 AND posted_by = $2
     )
INSERT INTO commentsvoted (id, user_id, votes, thread_id) 
    VALUES($1, $2, true, $3);
```